# Google Maps Autocomplete - Strange Issue (iOS)

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We have just developed an iPhone app that has a feature that relies on the Google Maps' Autocomplete API. The feature works on all our devices, except one, which is an iPhone 4 with 5.0.1 OS.

Here is the resulting error message from XCode log:

```
Aug 20 11:46:47 unknown HenryContainer[158] <Warning>: autocomplete: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Nor&types=(cities)&components=country:au&sensor=true&key=KEYGOESHERE
Aug 20 11:46:48 unknown timed[313] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Want active time in 39.25hrs. Need active time in 122.58hrs.

Aug 20 11:46:48 unknown HenryContainer[158] <Warning>: ASIHTTPRequest request_didFail:
Aug 20 11:46:48 unknown HenryContainer[158] <Warning>: ASIHTTPRequest request.url: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Nor&types=(cities)&components=country:au&sensor=true&key=KEYGOESHERE
Aug 20 11:46:48 unknown HenryContainer[158] <Warning>: ASIHTTPRequest request.delegate: <GooglePlacesService: 0x7c6fbd0>
Aug 20 11:46:48 unknown HenryContainer[158] <Warning>: ASIHTTPRequest request.error: Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=1 "A connection failure occurred: SSL problem (Possible causes may include a bad/expired/self-signed certificate, clock set to wrong date)" UserInfo=0x3207a0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7c7d6f0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -9800.)", NSLocalizedDescription=A connection failure occurred: SSL problem (Possible causes may include a bad/expired/self-signed certificate, clock set to wrong date)}
Aug 20 11:46:48 unknown HenryContainer[158] <Warning>: ASIHTTPRequest request.postBody: (null)

Aug 20 11:46:58 unknown timed[313] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Not setting system time to 08/20/2012 01:46:58 from NTP because time is unchanged
Aug 20 11:46:58 unknown timed[313] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Not setting time zone to Australia/Sydney from NITZ
```

I've checked the clock time on the phone and all is as it should be. Google Maps application works fine on this phone and it is not jailbroken. The app will have a pretty large distribution, so I'm also wanting to know the likelihood of this occuring on another phone as well. We've also re-installed the app several times.

Any help would be most appreciated.

UPDATE: This appears to be affecting iOS 5.0 on a 3GS.

Comment: `A connection failure occurred` seems to indicate those devices are unable to connect. Are the devices that are unable to connect not connected to wifi or visa versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've since resolved the issue, had something to do with how iOS handles SSL.